# Highlight selected item in array and cycle through

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I have this ["gameboard"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnuqm.jpg) which simulates a DnD game. It is turn based but these 5 have already been sorted (left to right) according to a certain value. But now I would like to highlight the player who's turn it is, and use those "next" and "previous" buttons to cycle through it. This is what I have:

```
<div class="heroWrapper">
 <div class="image hero" *ngFor="let participant of participants">
  <img [src]="participant.imageUrl"/>
  <span class="HP">{{participant.hitPoints}}</span>
  <span class="namePlayer" *ngIf="isHero(participant)"> 
  {{getPlayerName(participant)}}</span>
  <span class="nameHero">{{participant.name}}</span>
 </div>
</div>

selectedParticipant: number = 0;

next(){
++this.selectedParticipant;
}

previous(){
if(this.selectedParticipant != 0){
  --this.selectedParticipant;
} else {
  this.selectedParticipant = this.participants.length -1;
 }
}
```

I bound it using ngClass, but nothing it showing:

```
<div class="heroWrapper">
 <div class="image hero" *ngFor="let participant of participants; index as i">
  <img [src]="participant.imageUrl" [ngClass]="{selected: 
  selectedParticipant  == participant[i]}"/>
  <span class="HP">{{participant.hitPoints}}</span>
  <span class="namePlayer" *ngIf="isHero(participant)"> 
  {{getPlayerName(participant)}}</span>
  <span class="nameHero">{{participant.name}}</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

Solution as given by qUest, modified a bit due to my CSS mess:

```
<div class="heroWrapper">
 <div class="image hero" *ngFor="let participant of participants; index as 
 i" [class]="i === selectedParticipant ? 'selected hero' : 'image hero'" >
 <img [src]="participant.imageUrl" />
 <span class="HP">{{participant.hitPoints}}</span>
 <span class="namePlayer" *ngIf="isHero(participant)"> {{getPlayerName(participant)}}</span>
 <span class="nameHero">{{participant.name}}</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily assign the class with a simple binding:

```
// compare with participant
<div *ngFor="let p of participants" [class.selected]="p === selectedParticipant">
    ...
</div>

// compare with number
<div *ngFor="let p of participants; let i = index" [class.selected]="i === selectedParticipant">
    ...
</div>
```

Class "selected" will be assigned to the div element whenever participant is selected.

Comment: it's not working, i thought maybe because the div where I put it in already had a class but I moved it and it still didn't work.

Comment: @Audiosleef make sure that validation p === selectedParticipant returns proper result. I've noticed in your code that you are assigning number to selectedParticipant which is not a good approach. You should pass a Participant object.

Comment: Isn't it easier to return a number if I will have to use the next() and previous() methods?

Comment: @Audiosleef I have edited my answer if you want to stick with number ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) If it doesn't work, there's problem elsewhere. Would help a lot if you shared some plunker/codepen - live example.